# copy a string from one locaion to another inside a file using python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a c file where i Need to find certain variables and write to variable Segment inside the same file. such as I find all variables starting as COND and define this as a bool in the gobal variable Segment.

I have to do this in python scripts.

I wrote a regular Expression to find all variables and one to find where to define These variables.

But I could not go there from there how to copy this variables to global variable Location.

```
rp = re.compile(r"(COND_[a-zA-Z_]*)")
rp1 = re.compile(r"(.*globale Variablen.*\s*\n.*)")
```

Now i Need to write rp below rp1 Location as bool rp = False;

Comment: If `[aA-zZ]` is meant to match letters, you should actually use `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: if i write {[a-zA-Z]} it is expecting lower case after COND_

Comment: It does not. `[a-zA-Z]` = `[A-Za-z]` and does not require lowercase letter to be the first one.

Comment: thats Right. I tried it worked. i may have misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

I have written something like the following which is giving what I want.

```
import os
import re

fh = open('filename.c', "r")
filecontent = fh.read()
fh.close()
src_changed = False

rp = re.compile(r"(COND_[a-zA-Z_]*)")
rp1 = re.compile(r"(.*globale Variablen.*\s*\n.*\n)")
matches = rp.findall(filecontent) #find all conditions
matches = list(set(matches)) #remove the duplicate strings from the matches

def repl(m):
    a = rp1.findall(filecontent)
    return "".join(a)+"bool " + m + " = False;"

for i in range(len(matches)):
    replword = repl(matches[i])
    filecontent = re.sub(r"(.*globale Variablen.*\s*\n.*)",replword, filecontent)
    src_changed = True

if src_changed:
    fh = open('filename.c', "w")
    fh.write(filecontent)
    fh.close()
```